# Insert checkbox caption in Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following inserts an autotext element in a Word document

```
NormalTemplate.AutoTextEntries("ap_pressurefilter").Insert _ 
        Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
```

but how do I insert the caption of a checkbox (checkbox1.Caption) in the document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

```
Selection.Text = checkbox.Caption
```